# Posting updated Address to the database MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm still learning how to use MVC 5, and so far I manage to get custom fields for my user profiles seen here in my manage view page:

http://puu.sh/ddmVY/2533472010.png

The user registers and fills out these fields and they are stored in the same place as the username and password data are stored. 
I added these fields right under the ApplicationUser in the IdentityModels.cs as seen here

```
 public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {

        // Additional user fields needed for registration
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string State { get; set; }
        public int ZipCode { get; set; }


        public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
        {
            // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
            var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
            // Add custom user claims here
            return userIdentity;
        }
    }
```

I want to be able to edit the address so that if someone moves they can update it on their own. I have the method to get the data and put them inside the textboxes in the ChangeAddress view, but when it comes time to update the data I’m not sure how to go about that. I'm not sure how to write that post method Here is what the page looks like below and I was hoping to add this in the method in the ManageController.cs. I've seen other tutorials that have it done on a separate table but not the one from the ApplicationUser.

http://puu.sh/ddn98/96cab8a252.png

My method to display the data in the ChangeAddress view page

```
// GET: /Manage/ChangeAddress
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult> ChangeAddress()
        {

             ApplicationUser user = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId());

            var model = new ChangeAddressViewModel
            {
                Address = user.Address,
                City = user.City,
                State = user.State,
                ZipCode = user.ZipCode

            };
            return View(model);
        }
```

Comment: Yeah I'm still stuck on what I need to do if someone can provide additional help that would be great. I'm using EF 6.0 if that changes anything.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass something in the model that will allow you to identify which user the data belongs to when it comes back. It would be easiest to add a UserId property to the ChangeAddressViewModel.

You pass this back with the other data in the ChangeAddressViewModel record when you make your request to the get. This information then populates your view typically in a form that can be submitted back via POST. You typically put the UserId into a HiddenField so that its present in the form but not shown.

You can then create an update method on your controller that has a [HttpPost] attribute which takes a ChangeAddressViewModel as its input parameter and then you wire up your form so that the submit posts to that update action.

Inside your new update method. locate the desired user using the userId that you have been passed back. Set the various updated values of that user from the values obtained from the  ChangeAddressViewModel that was passed in by the POST.

On your DB context, for your user record call SaveCnanges() to update the record in via EF.

[There is a step by step tutorial for MVC on asp.net](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/examining-the-edit-methods-and-edit-view)

Comment: Does this tutorial linked still apply to the Identity 2.0 related stuff? I see stuff like this for other post methods below:

`[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> VerifyPhoneNumber(VerifyPhoneNumberViewModel model)`

While the tutorial is showing me this: 

`[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include="ID,Title,ReleaseDate,Genre,Price")] Movie movie)`

Also They have this line: `db.Entry(movie).State = EntityState.Modified;`
Would the applicationUser the default one I'm using be something like `db.Entry(ApplicationUser).State?`

Comment: Synchronous method calls and sync still both apply - you just choose the appropriate approach for your action as your require it. You can pass in a POCO (in this case a ChangeAddressViewModel and you don't have to bind it yourself it will auto bind as long as your form data has properties that match the property names on the POCO. Calling SaveChanges will update the state.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I manage to help myself and came up with solution to my problem. Posting it here for anyone who has a similar problem to mine.

```
    // 
    // POST: /Manage/ChangeAddress
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> ChangeAddress(ChangeAddressViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            // Get the current application user
            var user = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId());
            if (user != null)
            {
                //grab the details
                user.Address = model.Address;
                user.City = model.City;
                user.State = model.State;
                user.ZipCode = model.ZipCode;

                // Update the user
                var result = await UserManager.UpdateAsync(user);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", new { Message = ManageMessageId.ChangeAddressSuccess });
                }
                AddErrors(result);
                return View(model);
            }
        }
        return View(model);
    }
```